# Is there a way to use setTimeout in Gnome Shell Extension code?

Tags: application-development, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, javascript

I am trying to code a gnome-shell extension. It uses Javascript. But one major problem when I want to use `setTimeout()` it tells me this in the log: `ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined`, what I am going to reach here is I want to call a function in non-blocking way using `setTimeout()`. Maybe one of you has met this issue before or you may have a solution/alternative for me.

Comment: `setTimeout`  is not part of ECMAScript so it is possible that a framework does not supply it. Try with `window.setTimeout()` (the difference: global and local timeout).

Comment: `this._timeout = Mainloop.timeout_add_seconds(10, Lang.bind(this, this.{function}));` works as a timeout to {function}.

Comment: It works, of course with `const Mainloop = imports.mainloop;` at the top. Thanks for the help.

Comment: make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to capture this in an answer:

```js
const Mainloop = imports.mainloop;

...

Mainloop.timeout_add(1000, () => log('one second later!'));
```

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693413/extension-event-loop-in-gnome-3-10-vs-3-14).